# Visual Studios 2010 source config issues

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup, source-code

I have a VS solution set up with my own code. My code also uses some third party code which I have access to, but do not want to put into my project. However, I do want to be able to look at the other source code (not just the metadata).

While I am debugging I can do this fine; I can put breakpoints in and see the full code, but when I am not using the debugger and I try to jump to declaration I just get the metadata. What do I need to fix in my configurations?